# How to make a picture program for gps

Tags: gps

How can I re-program a gps with my own software? I'm new to this but i think i have to write all 0's to the hard disk to wipe it clean first. Then from there what program can i download or use to build my own software to make a picture/audio to put on the device. To transform it from a gps to a digital picture frame basically.. I need help so can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to flash custom firmware to the device - a process that requires a lot of expertise, as well as information about the specifics of the hardware - which is likely not to be publicly disclosed. It's highly unlikely you're going to be able to pull this off.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I can get the hardware information i'm sure, but what firmware would i flash to the device? Is there something already out there or would the firmware have to be created by me as well? This seems to be a big task and i would love to accomplish it.

Comment: No, you probably cannot get the hardware information. You will have to create your custom firmware as well as figure out **everything**. There is no way anyone can help you without knowledge of which GPS unit, and even then it would require a *lot* of work.

Comment: So basically when something is hard or a lot of work, no one will help but yet advise to walk away from the problem/situation/project? Let me ask this then, is there anything else i can use then? Like say a digital camera, which already can have pictures on it. But can i make it so when it turns on it goes directly to a picture and plays audio with it? I don't see how my ideas are so far fetched. Seems very possible. I just need someone who acquires the knowledge!